# How to visualize this pass traffic data between players in R?

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I have a pass traffic data from a Basketball Match, I have 100+ rows which indicate passes between Players of the same team, like this :

```
   Player
1  21
2  12
3   5
4  21
5  12
6   2
7  12
8   5
9   3
..
```

I want to visualize this data, like the image below. At every row, I want to draw a line between Players. For example, after 1st row, ball moves to "Player 12" from "Player 21", at that moment, I want to draw a line between "Player 21 and 12", direction doesn't matters.

sample image : http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/9885/samplex.gif

I also want to give color to these lines [ creating a Color Legend ] which will state how many passes occur between Players. For example, if the line between "Players 12 and 21" is "Green", this will mean that passes between them are above "XXX", according to "Color Legend".

How can I visualize this ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give some sample data that we actually can read, e.g. the output of `dput(yourData[1:20])`? Do you have coordinates of the positions of the players?

Comment: @Thilo You can download Sample from there : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/akqmnmfpg4mqjs9/Sample.csv)
Actually I haven't calculated the coordinates yet, you can simply give random values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach using `ggplot2`. Using ideas from [this post](http://dgkontopoulos.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/setting-a-background-image-in-ggplot2/) we add a background image by converting it to `*.ppm` with ImageMagick. Positions of the players are in `coords`, so you might want to change them, but because of `ylim` and `xlim` they will remain in the right area.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pixmap)

data <- data.frame(Player = c(2, 12, 21, 5, 3, 21, 5, 12, 3, 12, 21, 5))
p <- data.frame(Pass1 = data[-nrow(data), ], Pass2 = data[-1, ])
p <- apply(p, 1, function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse = " "))
p <- factor(table(p)[p])
coords <- replicate(2, runif(nrow(unique(data))))
xmap <- setNames(coords[,1], unique(data$Player))
ymap <- setNames(coords[,2], unique(data$Player))
plotData <- data.frame(x = xmap[as.character(data$Player)], 
                       y = ymap[as.character(data$Player)],
                       Player = factor(data$Player))
plotData <- plotData[rep(1:nrow(plotData), each = 2),]
plotData <- cbind(plotData[-c(1, nrow(plotData)),], id = rep(p, each = 2))
image <- read.pnm("p.ppm")

as.raster.pixmapRGB <- function(x) {
  nr <- nrow(x@red)
  r <- rgb((x@red), (x@green), (x@blue))
  dim(r) <- x@size
  r
}

ggplot(plotData, aes(x = x, y = y, label = Player)) +
  annotation_raster(image, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf, interpolate = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(vjust = -1, colour = "red") + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
  geom_point(size = 5) + geom_path(aes(colour = id)) + xlim(c(-0.1, 1.1)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Number of passes") + ylim(c(-0.1, 1.1))
```

Comment: @ Julius : It gave 2 errors. 1st:Error in file(file, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file 'p.ppm': No such file or directory
and 2nd:
Error in UseMethod("as.raster") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.raster'

Comment: @forochelian, you can find this particular image already converted [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e7ahsbu30yogd9/p.ppm). You will have to use that ImageMagick software in case you want to use another one.

Answer (score 1):

James Kierstead has a slopegraph example using R at http://www.jameskeirstead.ca/r/slopegraphs-in-r/

David Ruau has a slopegraph R program at https://github.com/bobthecat/codebox/blob/master/table.graph.r

Nathan Yau, in his book *Visualize This*, has a nice sample using a slopegraph. If I recall correctly (don't have the book with me now), he uses R.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any chord diagrams using R (See below).

---

**Java options**

Ben Fry has a [slopegraph demo using Java/Processing](http://benfry.com/salaryper/)

---

**JavaScript options**

If you're willing to try JavaScript, there are a few options using [D3](http://d3js.org/):

- Chord diagram -- 2 examples: [simple chord](http://bl.ocks.org/4062006) or [uberdata](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/)
- Slopegraph -- [example](http://skedasis.com/d3/slopegraph/)

See the [D3 gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) for lots more examples.

Answer (score 0):

In R, a **chord diagram** can be used for this purpose, by means of the [**circlize**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/) package